# Path of external component template or css when compiling TypeScript to outDir

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-components

When I code Angular 2 apps, my `tsconfig.json` file contains the following parameter:

```
"outDir": "dist"
```

meaning the TypeScript-to-JavaScript compilation will store generated files in the `dist` folder.

My problem is when I try using components which have an external template or CSS file **and** which use [component-relative paths](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html), like so:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent { }
```

The browser tries to load the `.html` and `.css` files from the same folder where the transpiled JavaScript file is located — under `dist`. But these files only exist in the original folder (where the original TypeScript file is located).

How to solve this?

Note: The code works if I remove `moduleId: module.id` and I use absolute paths, e.g. `app/my-cmp/my.component.html`, but it's not what I want. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want your JavaScript to output to the *dist* folder, assuming for distribution, then you can create a script that copies the html and css to the *dist* folder as well. Usually you can run some sort of minification on those files that makes doing that more worthwhile.

Another alternative is to reference these paths relatively through the root directory. So for example, if you have a file `/someDir/myfile.ts` and `/someDir/my.component.html` then you can reference `my.component.html` by doing `../someDir/my.component.html`. That will work if `/someDir/myfile.ts` goes to `/dist/myfile.js`. The downside to this is that it will probably get annoying to do once your project grows and so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, David. Too bad there isn't a more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 0):

module.id is just the path of generated JavaScript file (e.g., http://localhost:8080/dist/app/my.component.js). You can omit dist with module.id.replace('dist', '') to accomplish what you want:

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id.replace('dist', ''),
  selector: 'my-cmp',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['my.component.css']
})
```