# typescript outdir misses html files

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I have this angular 2 structure mainly created by following the [angular 2 QuickStart guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html):

```
│   index.html
│   package.json
│   systemjs.config.js
│   tsconfig.json
│   typings.json
│
├───app
│   │   app.component.ts
│   │   app.module.ts
│   │   app.routes.ts
│   │   main.ts
│   │
│   ├───components
│   │       login.component.html
│   │       login.component.ts
│   │       nav-bar.component.html
│   │       nav-bar.component.ts
│   │       project-detail.component.html
│   │       project-detail.component.ts
│   │       project-list.component.html
│   │       project-list.component.ts
│   │
│   ├───models
│   │       person.ts
│   │       project.ts
│   │
│   └───services
│           login.service.ts
│
└───dist
```

I tried to setup a dist folder for compiled sources in `tsconfig.ts`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

But now I am not sure how to reference the html files in the components `templateUrl`. In `login.component.ts` I have this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

After `npm start` the html files are missing from the dist folder. In `app.routes.ts` I set up to redirect to teh login page on empty route path. Then I get this error in the browser:

```
zone.js:486 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load http://localhost:3000/dist/components/login.component.html(…)
```

How to setup the outDir correctly? Thanks

**UPDATE**

My `npm start` script section from `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
```

Comment: What does your npm start script look like?

Comment: tsc doesn't handle any of the html files, you should copy those separately. for example with grunt.

Comment: @toskv thanks, i will look at it, I dont know grunt yet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Path of external component template or css when compiling TypeScript to outDir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813809/path-of-external-component-template-or-css-when-compiling-typescript-to-outdir)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
```

for this:

```
templateUrl: 'app/components/login.component.html'
```

if you're moving the file with Grunt you may need to change the url for correct file path.

Comment: thanks, I will look at grunt, didnt know about it. And should I move the index.html too? because now the index is not in dist but it is handling the page load what is little weird as I thought about the `dist` folder being something like `target` in java apps - as a standalone, deploy-ready app folder.